# My ArcGIS online map keeps breaking, says it can't show base map

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-online-basemaps, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I have an ArcGIS online map I have made here: http://arcg.is/2gTY9wt

It seems to work fine while I am editing it and then save it and open it.

But if I come back the next day and open it again it gives me the message "Something went wrong, the map did not load correctly."

Even if I change the base map and resave it it will seem to work then (but not always). But if I open it later it seems to have that basemap problem.

So I am looking for a way to save the correct basemap into each of maps and have the application show all of them.

Actually the link in the question is it to the web app. But I actually want the 5 maps in the app. I will place the links for each of the maps here. But now it isn't even opening the map with the data.

http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=de9a0021338a4fafad3320cdb06123a9

Comment: BTW: If I go to the each of the 5 maps that comprise the web app. It says "Basemap is not available. Displaying the default basemap instead." and the map doesn't show any of the data. Don't understand why it worked for a while and now seems to be working. Could it have something to do with "HTTPS"??

Comment: Actually the link in the question is it to the web app. But I actually want the 5 maps in the app. I will place the links for each of the maps here.

Comment: What browser are you seeing this in? If you can open up the developer console when you load the map/app to see what errors come through. The https doesnt seemt o be the issue, I can load the app over https.

Comment: Which basemap is giving you trouble? I opened your link above and all basemaps came through fine.

Comment: I am using the latest version of Chrome. That's a good idea about the dev console will check now...

Comment: Thx Mary Beth!! can you open this map and will it show the base map? http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6d8ee86a5ec1480ebcb2bfb02a45ab8f

Comment: above link works.

Comment: Here is a link to a doc with screen prints of what I am seeing. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gq0C4MxUaOoPsMBS8uIBK_I1Y6Fe8gP-JSugXomWO5k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The above link also worked for me. Are you using a custom base map that is giving you the error? Or one of ESRI's provided maps?

Comment: I am using one of the ESRI provided basemaps. I edited that doc with the code that results in Chromes Dev Console and image of what I see. Pls see https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gq0C4MxUaOoPsMBS8uIBK_I1Y6Fe8gP-JSugXomWO5k/edit?usp=sharing...

Comment: Something I forgot to mention is that I am in the Houston Public Library at the moment and using their network so there could be some sort of security issue. But the users for this map will often be at the library so I need to find a way to address this issue.

Comment: OK I figured out that it is a browser issue. All the maps work fine in IE and Firefox and the problem is only on Chrome. But I anticipate that most of my users will be using Chrome (or Chrome on Android) to view the map so I still need to figure out how to fix the issue, if there is a fix.

Comment: You may need to add these to the trusted sites in Chrome:  http://*.arcgis.com, https://*.arcgis.com, http://*.arcgisonline.com, and https://*.arcgisonline.com.

Comment: Thx again, but I need for the maps to work in multiple computers in places like public libraries so I can't add individual exceptions to machines. I saw this one solution but don't know how to implement it yet.

Comment: because the basemap establishes the coordinate system of the map. Once you save a map with a basemap, the map viewer only uses that basemap; it doesn't revert to a default basemap if yours is unavailable. You can repair your map by using a different basemap as long as the spatial reference of the bad and new basemap are the same. For basemaps that are tile layers, the tiling scheme of the bad and new basemaps must also be the same. Repair your map by choosing a different basemap from the gallery or using the URL parameter basemapUrl.

Comment: I feel like the answer is here somewhere by encoding the basemapUrl into the URL: http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/use-url-parameters.htm But for the time being I will just use firefox as a workaround.

Comment: Hello all: sorry to be a bother but I am still having the same issue. I thought the browser was the issue but this morning now getting the same error in both IE and Chrome. The maps won't load. If I can't fix this then my app is dead in the water.. http://arcg.is/2gTY9wt

Comment: Here is what I am seeing https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UtTA5FJa3p9M6fJP0HMFhz8KQqTMgU0nn9FzjZI5_Js/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You map loads fine for me in chrome, ie, ff.   Great map BTW. 
You need to upload a fiddler log or a HAR file from the browser where you can replicate the issue.  This will let us inspect the errors.  I assume you cannot replicate on a device outside of the library WiFi?